# What is the equivalent of a Table Valued Parameter (TVP) SQL Server insert in ElasticSearch?

Tags: .net, sql-server, elasticsearch, datatable, table-valued-parameters

In SQL Server, we can define a [Table Valued Parameter (TVP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) that would contain the same structure as a DataTable in .Net.

On the application layer, we can populate a DataTable with thousands of records, then send that table as a single parameter to a SQL Server stored procedure for a bulk insert.

What would an equivalent strategy be with ElasticSearch?

Comment: Table Valued Parameter is used to pass multiple rows, same can be achieved in Elasticsearch using  BulkRequest

`BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();


bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet", "1")
        .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                        .field("user", "kimchy")
                        .field("postDate", new Date())
                        .field("message", "trying out Elasticsearch")
                    .endObject()
                  )
        );
`

Comment: Why not put that as an answer so I can check it? ;)